# Javascript button not working on android mobile for website

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

So I've been trying to get a button to work on my phone (Android) running Firefox. I've tried changing from the onClick to on('click touchstart' that was recommended on other posts here without success. I also added cursor: pointer to my css file for the button. Not sure what else to do. Maybe something to do with hover?
I'm using jquery 1.12.0

```js
$(".add-to-cart").on('click touchstart',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
    var price = Number($(this).attr("data-price"));
    RWC_shoppingCart.addItem(name, price, 1);
    RWC_shoppingCart.displayCart();
    RWC_shoppingCart.saveCart();
});
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-box-caption">
    <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
        <div class="project-category text-faded">
            <h2>$30</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="project-name">
            Short Candles
        </div>
        <br>
        <button class="add-to-cart btn btn-default btn-xl" href="#" data-name="Short Candle" data-price="30.00">Add To Cart</button>
        <!--
             <form paypal stuff
             </form>
        -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it didn't work only on firefox on android?

Comment: Is this the only instance of `.add-to-cart` on the page?

Comment: Buttons do not take a href attribute.. and it is not needed in your case anyway. Remove the href attribute and also try removing the preventDefault from your js.

Comment: @Joint I tried it on Opera and still no go The button seems to look pressed, as in it turns a slightly darker shade but without activating the javascript function

Comment: @Phix Yes it's the only instance in the .js file

Comment: @scooterlord i removed href first, and then commented out the preventDefault with the same outcome where the button seems to look pressed, as in it turns a slightly darker shade but without activating the javascript function